# Get data through a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a service called servcises/employees.js:

```
angular.module('dashyAppApp')
  .service('employees', function () {
    this.getEmployees = function() {
      return $.get( '/data/employee.json' );
    };
  });
```

This service is suppose to read the json file in the data folder.

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
        "country": "Cameroon",
        "employ_count": 50,
    },
    {
        "country": "United States",
        "employ_count": 738
    }
]
}
```

Here is my controllers/main.js :

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, employees, Markers) {
    var _this = this;
    employees.getEmployees().then(
      function(data) {
    _this.items = data;
      }
    );
});
```

And here is my view:

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in main.items.countries">
      <h4>{{item.country}}</h4>
    </div>
```

unfortunately nothing is being displayed. I am not sure of what am doing wrong.

Comment: `console.log(_this.items);` what prints?

Comment: @developer033  It logs undefined outside the .then function and nothing inside the .then function

Comment: why are you using the JQuery `$.get` method here? You should be using angular's `$http.get` method instead.

Comment: I don't see where you put items into $scope.

Comment: @danh I have other code in the controller using the scope variable but that isn't the problem because even when I take all of that out.. nothing changes.

Comment: @danh he accesses the controller via `main`. He must have `MainCtrl as main ` somewhere in his code !

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj, instead of taking out references to scope elsewhere, add it after the get completes `$scope.main.items = data`

Comment: @dahn, it doesn't matter... he's using `controller-as-syntax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to get data via AngularJS:

```
angular.module('dashyAppApp')
  .service('employees', function ($http) {
    this.getEmployees = function() {
      return $http.get( '/data/employee.json' );
    };
  });
```

And additional it seems that you JOSN has an extra comma after `"employ_count": 50`. Can you try removing it?

Comment: I tried that .. but I get this weird error :`SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 70`. My json is not even up to 20 lines.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 70 ... My json is not even up to 20 lines.

Comment: Look at your server side.. maybe the error is there now.

Comment: I get a response now. I had an error in my json. But still can't get to display it in my view : `<div  ng-repeat="item in main.items.countries">
      <h4>{{item.country}}</h4>
    </div>`

Comment: `console.log(_this.items);` is **defined** now?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj can I try as I mentioned in the answer removing extra comma?

Comment: @developer033 I get a 200 ok response  but it wouldn't display in the view.. `Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}`